# Read data from file using Java 8?

Tags: java

I am trying to convert this piece of code to Java 8 with streams. I am reading from a file which has 3 or more columns. This depends on how many grades does a student have. The first Column contains the name of the student. The second one contains the gender of the student. The next columns the grades. The delimiter is a comma. I want to have the values in the variables the same way as I have down below.

```
@Override
    public List<Student> processFile(String filename) {
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader( new File(filename)));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null) {
                String[] splitline = line.split(",");
                String name = splitline[0];
                String gender = splitline[1];
                int[] grades = new int[splitline.length -2];

                for(int i = 2; i < splitline.length; i++){
                    grades[i - 2] = Integer.parseInt(splitline[i]);
                }

                students.add(new Student(name, gender, grades));
                line=reader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        students.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getName));
        return students;
    }
```

After this I want to get the Students with tens, which I do the following way:

```
private void printStudentsWithTens(List<Student> students) {
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder("Name of Students with tens: ");
       res.append(students.stream()
                .filter(student -> Arrays.stream(student.getGrades()).anyMatch(g -> g == 10))
                .map(student -> student.getName().split(" ")[0])
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));

        System.out.println(res);
    }
```

Comment: It already looks clean. If you want to learn the `Stream` API, learn from the tutorial available [here](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html) and [here](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html).

Comment: What if a student has a comma in their name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```java
try(BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)))) {
    return r.lines()
        .map(line -> line.split(","))
        .map(this::loadStudent)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::getName))
        .collect(toList());
}

...

private static Student loadStudent(String[] splitline) {
    // TODO - the grades code you already have
    return new Student(splitline[0], splitline[1], grades);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The issue is that I won't be able to get the values from the getter methods from the Student class. I need to get the values using the getters.

Comment: @EnyediDavid Not sure what you mean, why would that code prevent you being able to use getter methods?  And why would you need to _get_ anything in the code you posted?  If there is another aspect to the question relating to the `Student` class then please post that code and amend the question accordingly.

Comment: I just added, what I want to do with the getter methods. I am a beginner, so do you mind explaining the loadStudent(String[]) helper method. By explaining I mean, how can I use that to get the same results.

Comment: The helper method `Student loadStudent(String[] data)` can be replaced with a constructor in `Student` class: `public Student(String[] data)` which could be referred later as `.map(Student::new)`

Comment: I've added an outline for the helper method to the answer, should (hopefully) be obvious how to refactor the code you already have into the new method, or follow the suggestion from @AlexRudenko.  I still don't understand your question regarding getters as the new code is just the stream equivalent of the imperative loop you posted, I expect the `Student` class would be unaffected.

Comment: I managed to resolve the problem. Now I know my question about the getters was stupid. Sorry for that. Thank you for your help!